# Git 2.6.3 and Visual Studio 2013 / 2015 integration

Tags: git, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-2015

I am facing a weird issue with Visual Studio. GIT integration was fine until I upgraded my entire system. I am running a VM on Mac OSX El Capitan (using VMWare Fusion 8.0.2). Here is what I upgraded:

- Windows 7 -> Windows 10
- Visual Studio 2013 Professional -> Visual Studio 2015 Enterprise
- Git 1.9.x -> Git 2.6.3

With Git 2.6.3 installed, all my files in the Solution Explorer show the red check ("Pending Edit"). However, there are no changes to the file and instead they should show the blue lock symbol. With this issue, I can not see in the Solution Explorer which files have been changed. I noticed that this had to do with the Git upgrade. I moved back to Git 1.9.5 and the Visual Studio integration works as it should. The issue appears in VS 2013 as well as in VS 2015.

Anybody else experienced the same problem? And is there a known workaround to make the latest Git release compatible to Visual Studio?

Here are picture to display the issue in the Solution Explorer:

With Git 2.6.3 all files look like this: [image]

With Git 1.9.5 files are correctly identified as unmodified:[image]

Comment: Can you try and restart everything after typing git config --global core.autocrlf false?

Comment: @VonC I restarted everything after changing the autocrlf. It still shows a wrong state; however, once i modify a file and undo the changes, Git wants to commit the entire file again. After a test commit I noticed that from this point forward, the integration with Visual Studio works again. I am not sure if the change of the setting fixed it or the new commit did the change.

Comment: @VonC OK, I am more certain now that your solution is the CORRECT solution to this problem. Changing a file, undoing the changes (the file is marked as edited and shows up in changed files). After this, checkout the file from the repository and voila, the state of the file updates now correctly in Visual Studio. Thanks!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> all my files in the Solution Explorer show the red check ("Pending Edit").

This is probably due to a global setting which changes the eol (end of line) of all files on checkout.

```
git config --global core.autocrlf false
```

The [OP Alexander Fuchs](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4893736/alexander-fuchs) confirms [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33967950/git-2-6-3-and-visual-studio-2013-2015-integration/33969486#comment55695574_33967950):

> Changing a file, undoing the changes (the file is marked as edited and shows up in changed files).
>   After this, checkout the file from the repository and voila, the state of the file updates now correctly in Visual Studio.